# rb-appscript stopped working with Ruby 2.0.0 - patch ideas to make it work again?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, sourceforge-appscript

I know that rb-appscript is officially no longer supported.

However, I tried and found that rewriting existing libraries to use alternative methods (e.g. osascript) was a non-trivial work and it occurred to me that monkey-patching rb-appscript to work again seemed like a better approach, if ever possible.

Here's what happens.

```
$ rvm 2.0.0
$ gem install rb-appscript
$ irb
> require 'appscript'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- _aem/mactypes
from ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rb-appscript-0.6.1/lib/appscript.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
from ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
from ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
```

What change in Ruby 2.0.0 is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there was a bug in Rubygems 2.0.0, and upgrading to 2.0.2 by

```
gem update --system
```

fixed the problem.